# save and reuse TfidfVectorizer using pickle raises error

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle

I am having trouble saving my vectorizer and using it in a different script.

tokenize is a custom function

ngram_range = (1,3)

max_features = 5000

Here is where I save it:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, ngram_range=ngram_range, max_features=max_features)

X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train['text'])

pickle.dump(vectorizer, open('tfidf_vectorizer.p', 'wb'))
```

Here is where I load it and try to use it (data_list is a dictionary):

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(pickle.load(open('tfidf_vectorizer.p', 'rb')))
# this also causes the same error
# vectorizer = pickle.load(open('tfidf_vectorizer.p', 'rb'))
for x, art in enumerate(data_list):
    art['originalText'] = vectorizer.transform(art['originalText'])
```

And my error is:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'tokenize' on <module '__main__' from 'C:/.....file where I load and use......'>
```

Using the packages sklearn and pickle.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(pickle.load(open('tfidf_vectorizer.p', 'rb')))
```

Instead, try:

```
vectorizer = pickle.load(open('tfidf_vectorizer.p', 'rb'))
```

and then call the transform method

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is what I originally tried, should have put that in the post. That raises the same error though.

Comment: I Didn't get any error when I tried it. The only thing Different in my code was that I was not using any tokenizer. Are you using a custom tokenize function? Can you try without using one and see if that works?

Comment: Yes! so the issue was that I needed to import my custom function into the script where I load the vectorizer. Thank you!